# Modifying the Viewer Layout

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I a currently developing a Viewer based Web Application, and I would like the viewer itself to have a look that resembles the Navisworks Layout (I want the hierarchy tree to be on the left, and the properties of the selected object to be displayed on the right, outside of the screen itself instead of them being floating panels that cover the models when they are opened).

Is there a built-in way to achieve this within the viewer SDK?

Answer (score 0):

The viewer UI itself is built with vanilla HTML/CSS, so theoretically you *might* be able to reuse some of it outside of the viewer canvas but it's not an officially supported feature.

Another option would be to stay inside the viewer canvas, and modify the desired panels so that they remain attached to the side of the viewport, and can't be moved around. This could be done by either subclassing `Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel`, or potentially by modifying the existing model browser or property panels. Here's an example of a simple panel that would be attached to the left side of the viewer, and that couldn't be moved around:

```js
class MyCustomPanel extends Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel {
    constructor(container) {
        super(container, 'my-custom-panel', 'My Custom Panel');
        this.container.style.left = 0;
        this.container.style.top = 0;
        this.container.style.width = '350px';
        this.container.style.height = '100%';
        this.container.style.resize = 'none';
    }

    initialize() {
        this.title = this.createTitleBar(this.titleLabel || this.container.id);
        // this.initializeMoveHandlers(this.title); // Moving panel not allowed!
        this.container.appendChild(this.title);
        this.content = document.createElement('div');
        this.content.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        this.content.style.height = '100%';
        this.content.innerHTML = `<div>Hello world</div>`;
        this.container.appendChild(this.content);
    }
}

let panel = new MyCustomPanel(viewer.container);
panel.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, Petr. Would I be able to pass my custom panel extending from the Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ViewerModelStructurePanel to the ModelStructure extension (and property extension, respectively) directly when it is being loaded into the viewer, or would I also have to create a custom extension and overide the onToolBarCreated() method?

Comment: Essentially, I understand how to cumtomize docking panels and add them to my own extentions, but when it comes to modifying the built-in in panels of the two extensions mentioned previously while maintaining their same functionality, I am having a hard time understanding the proper way of doing so. I know it is posible because of the .setPanel() method that is mentioned on the documentation, but I don't seem to be able to figure it out.

Comment: The `Autodesk.ModelStructure` viewer extension has a method called `setModelStructurePanel` that you can use to set your own, customized panel to be opened instead of the default one.